# Show time/date on taskbar

Tags: windows-8, taskbar

Is there a way to show the time/date on the taskbar? (at the moment, all I can see is a little upwards-pointing arrow that shows hidden icons)

EDIT: Turns out that the time is shown by default and I'd managed to switch it off somehow. Oops!

Comment: Related: [View the current day in the taskbar](http://superuser.com/q/790399/354511).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The time (not the date) does show up by default. To (re)add it:

1. Right click on the taskbar
2. Click properties

   [[image: Screenshot]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYPZD.png)
3. Click `Customize...` for Notification Area

   [[image: Screenshot]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkJHy.png)
4. Click `Turn system icons on or off...`

   [[image: Screenshot]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsKMb.png)
5. Turn on `Clock`

   [[image: Screenshot]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMK3c.png)

Comment: I like your hastily drawn ovals :)

Comment: [FHC](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/133693) FTW!

Comment: This shows the time but not the date :-(

Comment: Luckily the next-highest voted answer explains how to show both the date and the time ... but unfortunately it is neither the accepted nor the highest-voted answer (yet).

Answer (score 15):

- Right click on the taskbar and select properties
- In the Notification area heading, click the Customize button
- Click on the "Turn system icons on or off"
- The first item should be clock. Select on instead of off.
- Click ok.

Additionally, if Time is seen but not Date, you might need to uncheck "Use small icons"

> You'll need to right click on the Taskbar, select Properties, then
>   uncheck the box for "Use small icons"
>   [image]

Taken from [this site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/7241ee9a-2592-48b5-9d2b-a3956b69c59d), hope it works.

Comment: +1 for the small icons tip, that was my problem..

Comment: Where is the "Use small icons" checkbox supposed to be? I'm not seeing it on Win8.1.

Comment: @nilskp added a quote from the linked site, with details

Comment: @KarthikT, yeah, I'm just not seeing that particular checkbox.

Comment: @nilskp hmm, I tested on my 8.1, I am seeing it.

Comment: @KarthikT can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @nilskp added, i see it as "Use small taskbar buttons"

Comment: Also, I noticed that if the taskbar is too small, it will auto-hide the date. If you followed this answer and still cant see the date, unlock the task bar and click and drag it to resize until it can fit the date.

Answer (score 12):

Actually I was searching for this too, but then I've discovered `Win+C` keyboard shortcut and I like it a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

3rd box down, it actually says "use small taskbar buttons"  My eyes skipped over it at first too, since I was looking for the word "icons".  Unchecking this brought the date back for me next to the time

Answer (score 0):

If Time is seen but not Date, and if your taskbar is set to be vertical, you can fix it by a combination of two things, in order to make the date fit the taskbar's width:

- Making the date string smaller, by going to: *Control Panel* --> *Region*, and then making the *Short Date:* format narrower, by f.ex. choosing to display years as 2 digits (m/d/yy). The month vs day ordering can be adjusted under the *Additional Settings --> Date*
- Unlocking the taskbar and adjusting its size to fit the date (as also indicated above by trav1s: [Show time/date on taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/495196/show-time-date-on-taskbar#comment1134285_495197) ).

If using a vertical taskbar, whether you use small icons or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the Use small taskbar button as well.
After some play around, accidentally found out there is a bug in Win8 that does not display this option.

Remedy
Use your mouse point to the upper edge of the taskbar, drag it upward so to increase the thickness. Now the 'Small Taskbar' button will be visible.