# View the current day in the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is there a way to view the current day (eg. Wednesday) next to the date and time in the taskbar?

I can never remember the day when I need it, so is there a way to add the day in the taskbar?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

- Go to the Start Menu, search for `Region and Language` and open it.
- Click `Additional Settings`
- Go to the `Date` tab
- Change the `Short date` to `dddd  dd/mm/yyyy`. A human would read that as `Day of week  day/month/year`

Note: This will also change the `Date Modified` column when viewing files in Windows Explorer.

[image]

Comment: This can also affect the way some software (e.g.: Office) handles date formats. My personal preference is `dddd yyyy-mm-dd` which shows the day of week, followed by the ISO-formatted date. I also suggest stretching your taskbar to two rows high so the clock and notification area doesn't take up so much screen width.

Comment: Alternate way to open the **Region and Language** control panel applet: press Win+R, type or paste `intl.cpl` in the text box, and press Enter.

Comment: @ṧнʊß This official article provides a comprehensive list: [Executing Control Panel Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Iszi: But if you enlarge the taskbar you get the day for free without changing the system date and time formats!!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Oh, you're right! I guess I never really noticed that since it's one of the first things I do on a new system - I do it more for the optimization of horizontal space on the taskbar than for date/time formatting.

Answer (score 5):

A simple, low-impact solution is simply to resize your taskbar to be three (or more) rows high:

[image]

Also, while this is not, strictly speaking, an answer to your question, we’re on the boundary of
[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) territory here. 
You want to find out the day of the week quickly, easily
(without having to switch to another window and/or run a command). 
So just hover your mouse over the date/time panel:

[image]

Comment: Two rows work fine for me in Win7 with Aero, and I just double-checked my regional settings to make sure the short date format wasn't changed on this system. Also, my tooltip *does* show day of week for additional clocks. The lines in the tooltip are, in order: Local Date, Local Time, (Add'l Clock 1), (Add'l Clock 2). The local date appears to be in "Long Date" format, and each time is represented as `ddd HH:mm` (e.g.: "Fri 11:44"). The time portion of the times in the tooltip appear to match my "Short Time" format, but I don't see where I've set the abbreviated day of week to be included.

Comment: (i.e.: I presume inclusion of the day-of-week abbreviation in the tooltip is automatic regardless of date/time format settings, but I'm not sure why this does not appear to be the case for @AndreasRejbrand.) I'll have to do some more testing on one of my VMs later.

Comment: Oh, I am very sorry. The day *is* shown, but it was abbreviated, so I missed it. My apologies.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Oh, cool. So I'm not insane. Now I'd just like to figure out why it takes 3 rows for Scott when 2 works fine for me. I'm guessing it has something to do with Aero, but that seems odd.

Comment: Confirmed. It's Aero. You need three rows without, but only two if it's on. Apparently, everything down there is bigger with Aero, so there's more room.

Comment: @Iszi: Yes, I previously had the weekday with two lines, and then I changed something that made it go away. It was some Display setting; may have been turning off Aero. I couldn't remember, and I didn't think it was worth reverse engineering it since shub's setup seemed to be the same as mine (i.e., two-row-high taskbar without weekday).

Comment: Yes, this is also a way, I had not thought of this. +1 good idea :)